# Spark Framework routing limitations

Tags: microservices, spark-java

I am attempting to use the Spark Framework to access some web pages, and am running against several apparent limitations in its handling 
of routes.

The first limitation appears to be in its handling of "GET" parameters. In order to process parameters passed with a GET request, Spark 
requires that you use the queryParams() method of the Request object. This is not a problem for a single parameter:

```
 http://localhost:8080/service?aparam=text
```

When this is received by a Spark server, calling the method as shown below:

```
String param = request.queryParams("aparam");
```

properly gets the string "text".

Unfortunately, this only appears to work with a single parameter. If I was to put in more than one parameter, like:

```
http://localhost:8080/service?aparam=text&another=avalue
```

and then use the queryParams method:

```
String param = request.queryParams("aparam");
String param2 = request.queryParams("another");
```

then param becomes "text avalue" and param2 becomes null.

Note that for some unknown reason, the only known way to get GET parameters is to use queryParams(). The actual parameter map that is part of the Request object is actually empty. It contains no parameter values at all!

A second (more critical) problem occurs when I load an actual web page. I can load a page like index.html using a route like the following:

```
      get("/service/:resource",DispController.getFile);
```

where :resource comes from the following http request:

```
http://localhost:8080/service/index.html
```

the HTML file gets loaded without problems. Unfortunately, if the HTML file has as part of its contents CSS or Javascript files, like the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/resource/script/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resource/style/mainpage.css" />
```

the route to those files is undefined and Spark fails to load them:

```
01:46:34.571 [qtp311145939-18] INFO  spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/resource/script/jquery-3.3.1.js] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [*/*]
01:46:34.574 [qtp311145939-15] INFO  spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/resource/style/mainpage.css] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [text/css,*/*;q=0.1]
```

Of course, one could put in new routes to make the server find the files:

```
get("/resource/script/:resource",DispController.getFile);
get("/resource/style/:resource",DispController.getFile);
```

the problem with doing that is that it couples the server to specific places to look for the style and javascript files. If you are trying to incorporate a different set of HTML files that use a different directory structure for finding these files, then you have to either create more new routes to accommodate them or edit the HTML files so that their javascript and style diles use the same structure. What is needed is a way to define a route that accepts any directories under the directory with the HTML so that when a request for a CSS file (for example) 
in a subdirectory comes in:

```
http://localhost:8080/service/style/mainpage.css
```

then the server will know to look into the "style" directory to find the CSS file.

NOTE: I did attempt to solve this problem using the staticFiles.location() and staticFiles.externalLocation() methods. They did not solve the problem.

Based on the above, I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to parse out the values of more than one parameter so that a request like:

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/service?aparam=text&another=avalue
   ```

can have its values (in this case "text" and "avalue" separately parsed out?

2. Is there a routing syntax thast I can use so that a file in a subdirectory like "style" can be accessed?
3. If there are ways to solve one or both problems, how can it be done?

I have read through the Spark Framework documentation and tutorials, and can find nothing about handling multiple get parameters (in fact, I found out about using the queryParam() method in Stack Ovwerflow, not in the Spark documentation!) or any really detailed information about routing syntax. Has anyone had to figure out how to solve these problems? Are they solvable? If so, how?

Comment: [Static files](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#exception-mapping). For query strings, it doesn't seem that spark likes those, instead preferring to specify data as part of the path, as in `http://localhost:8080/service/aparam/text/another/avalue`, or as the body of a `POST` request. But, maybe, [.queryMap()](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#response) will help.

Comment: Ouroborus, it looks like the use of queryMap does solve Question 1 of my post. As for the Static Files link you provided, I had read that part of the doco well before posting these questions. As I stated in my post (just before Question 1), I already tried using staticFiles. It did not solve my problem. So Question 2 of my post still needs a solution.

Comment: What's your root and how did you try to configure `staticFiles`?